# How to make a view conform to MapAnnotationProtocol

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a tappable `MapAnnotation` and whenever I try to customize the "look" of the annotation pin, I get the following error:

> Initializer 'init(coordinateRegion:interactionModes:showsUserLocation:userTrackingMode:annotationItems:annotationContent:)' requires that 'NavigationLink<PlaceAnnotationView, LocationDetailsView>' conform to 'MapAnnotationProtocol'

`Annotation` is defined by this:

```
struct Annotation: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let lat: String?
    let lng: String?
    var name: String
}
```

And the Map is defined by this:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) { place in
    NavigationLink {
        LocationDetailsView(place: place.name)
    } label: {
        PlaceAnnotationView(title: place.name)
    }
}
```

Have I forgotten to define something? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapannotationprotocol

> Don’t create types conforming to MapAnnotationProtocol protocol. Instead, use one of the framework-provided types MapAnnotation, MapMarker, and MapPin.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapannotation

Comment: This answer actually does not show how to resolve the issue, only links to sources that might contain the resolution. Can you improve by giving an example on what the correct answer could be for the OPs question?

Comment: @Pomo-J the solution is to use one of Apple’s types don’t attempt to make your own. As clearly stated in the answer.